# data shows in sqlite but indexoutof bound exception while populating in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am trying to populate some data from sqlite in recyclerview.At the time of insertion in sqlite I can see the inserted data in log but while displaying in recyclerview it shows indexOutOfBoundException.I could not find an answer on stack.I have posted my recyclerview OnBindViewHolder,my sqlite table and the code where I am inserting data.Please help me

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.queue_list_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  //  final QueueModel queueModel = queueList.get(position);
    queueModel = queueList.get(position);
    holder.surveyId.setText(queueModel.getName());
    holder.dateTime.setText(queueModel.getDateTime());
    holder.status.setText(queueModel.getStatus());
    if(!holder.status.getText().equals("Queued"))
    {
        holder.sync.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    //Toast.makeText(context,role,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    holder.sync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readFromFile(queueList.get(position).getFileName());
            //sendFormToServer(queueList.get(position).get);

        }
    });
    //holder.year.setText(entityModel.getYear());
    }
```

my sqlite table

```
public class QueueTable {
Context context;
public QueueModel queueModel;
public ArrayList<QueueModel> queueDetails;

public QueueTable() {
    //this.context=context;

}

public static String createTable() {
    return "CREATE TABLE " + QueueModel.TABLE + "(" + QueueModel.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + QueueModel.SURVEY_ID + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.SURVEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.JSON_SUBFORM + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.DATE_TIME + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.FILENAME + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.STATUS + " TEXT, " + QueueModel.EMP_ID + " TEXT)";
}


public void insert(QueueModel queueModel) {
//        entityDetails.clear();
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(Student.KEY_StudID, student.getStudentId());
    //values.put(LocationTableModel.ID, locationTableModel.getId());
    values.put(QueueModel.SURVEY_ID, queueModel.getSurveyId());
    values.put(QueueModel.SURVEY_NAME, queueModel.getName());
    values.put(QueueModel.JSON_SUBFORM, queueModel.getSubformJSON());
    values.put(QueueModel.DATE_TIME, queueModel.getDateTime());
    values.put(QueueModel.FILENAME, queueModel.getFileName());
    values.put(QueueModel.STATUS, queueModel.getStatus());
    values.put(QueueModel.EMP_ID, queueModel.getEmp_id());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(QueueModel.TABLE, null, values);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}

public ArrayList<QueueModel> getQueueDetails() {

    queueDetails = new ArrayList<QueueModel>();
    queueDetails.clear();
    //entityDetails.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
   /* String selectQuery =  " SELECT Location." + LocationTableModel.LOCATION_DATETIME
            + ", Location." + LocationTableModel.LOCATION_LATITUDE
            + ", Location." + LocationTableModel.LOCATION_LONGITUDE
            + ", Location." + LocationTableModel.LOCATION_PROVIDER;*/
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Queue";

    Log.d("QUEUE SELECT QUERY", selectQuery);

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            queueModel = new QueueModel();
            queueModel.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.ID)));
            Log.d("Queue row id", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.ID))));
            queueModel.setSurveyId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.SURVEY_ID)));
            Log.d("Queue survey id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.SURVEY_ID)));
            queueModel.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.SURVEY_NAME)));
            Log.d("Queue name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.SURVEY_NAME)));
            queueModel.setFileName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.FILENAME)));
            Log.d("Queue filename", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.FILENAME)));
            queueModel.setSubformJSON(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.JSON_SUBFORM)));
            Log.d("Queue subform json",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.JSON_SUBFORM)));
            queueModel.setEmp_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.EMP_ID)));
            Log.d("Queue emp_id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.EMP_ID)));
            queueModel.setDateTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.DATE_TIME)));
            Log.d("Queue datetime", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.DATE_TIME)));
            queueModel.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.STATUS)));
            Log.d("Queue status",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QueueModel.STATUS)));

            queueDetails.add(queueModel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();

    return queueDetails;

}


public void delete() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    db.delete(QueueModel.TABLE, null, null);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}

public long getProfilesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, EntityTableModel.TABLE);
    db.close();
    return count;
}


}
```

my insertion in sqlite

```
queueModel = new QueueModel();
queueModel.setName(completeFormSurveyId);
queueModel.setSurveyId(completeFormSurveyId);
queueModel.setFileName(completeJsonFilename);
queueModel.setSubformJSON(jsonWithSubFileLocation);
queueModel.setDateTime(dateTime);
queueModel.setStatus("Queued");
queueModel.setEmp_id(getPreference());
queueTable.insert(queueModel);
```

Comment: post your whole adapter code and logcat error as well

Comment: Thanks but I have already sorted it out myself and I have posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did is this and it worked.For all who may face the same issue

```
try {
        queueModel = queueList.get(position);
        holder.surveyId.setText(queueModel.getName());
        holder.dateTime.setText(queueModel.getDateTime());
        holder.status.setText(queueModel.getStatus());
        if (!holder.status.getText().equals("Queued")) {
            holder.sync.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```